# Java.io.Exception: Working Directory: null Environment: null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

I am trying to run a shell command from my application directory and I am getting "working directory null and environment null.

I have looked at several posts here but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Error:
Error running exec(). Command: [/data/user/0/com.netscout.iperf3_clientls] Working Directory: null Environment: null

```
    public void startApp() {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process process = null;
    String appFileDir = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
    // String commandLine = appFileDir + "/iperf3 -c 129.196.197.116 --forceflush -O3 -Z -P2";
    String commandLine = appFileDir + "ls";

   try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine, null, null);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            // output.append(line + "/n");
            Log.e("Line", String.valueOf(line));
            Log.e("output", String.valueOf(output));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Output", String.valueOf(e));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a working directory for the script to run from. Also I would suggest to use a `ProcessBuilder` for doing your job:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html